# react-bootstrap - login form - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have the following login.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Button, Form, FormControl, FormGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Login extends Component {

    render() {
        const {errorMessage} = this.props

        return (
            <Form inline>
                <FormGroup controlId="formInlineEmail">
                    <FormControl type="email" ref="username" placeholder="Email"/>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup controlId="formInlinePassword">
                    <FormControl type="password" ref="password"/>
                </FormGroup>
                <Button type="submit" onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}>
                    Login
                </Button>
                {errorMessage &&
                <p style={{color:'red'}}>{errorMessage}</p>
                }
            </Form>
        )
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        const username = this.refs.username
        const password = this.refs.password
        const creds = { username: username.value.trim(), password: password.value.trim() }
        this.props.onLoginClick(creds)
    }
}

Login.propTypes = {
    onLoginClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    errorMessage: PropTypes.string
}
```

When attempting to login I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0, _reactDom2.default) is not a function at Login.handleClick
```

if I avoid using `react-bootstrap` and do the following in my Login.js it works fine.

```
<div>
  <input type='text' ref='username' className="form-control" style={{ marginRight: '5px' }} placeholder='Username'/>
  <input type='password' ref='password' className="form-control" style={{ marginRight: '5px' }} placeholder='Password'/>
  <button onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)} className="btn btn-primary">
    Login
  </button>

  {errorMessage &&
    <p style={{color:'red'}}>{errorMessage}</p>
  }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask why but this works:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';
import { Button, ControlLabel, Form, FormControl, FormGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Login extends Component {

    handleSubmit(event) {
        const username = findDOMNode(this.refs.username)
        const password = findDOMNode(this.refs.password)
        const creds = { username: username.value.trim(), password: password.value.trim() }
        this.props.onLoginClick(creds)
    }

    render() {
        const {errorMessage} = this.props

        return (
            <Form inline>
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalEmail">
                    <ControlLabel>Email </ControlLabel>
                    <FormControl type="username" ref="username" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Email" />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                    <ControlLabel>Password </ControlLabel>
                    <FormControl type="password" ref="password" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Password" />
                </FormGroup>
                <Button onClick={(event) => this.handleSubmit(event)}>Login</Button>
                {errorMessage &&
                <p style={{color:'red'}}>{errorMessage}</p>
                }
            </Form>
        )
    }
}

Login.propTypes = {
    onLoginClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    errorMessage: PropTypes.string
}
```